# IdentityServer4 and Angular4

Tags: json, angular, identityserver4, form-data

I am building a test with IdentityServer4 to understand how it works, I got the server running but I am trying to use the /connect/token endpoint from Angular 4, so I built the json to send to the post but it doesn't work as json, I get a 400 bad request answer with the invalid request.
If I use form-data on postman I get a 200 OK with the token I want to test, so how do I actual send the data for IdentityServer4 from Angular 4 as form-data and not json, I have never done this so it is a bit hard for me to understand how to do it.
Thank you for any pointer.

Comment: did you look in tho this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750583/talking-to-identityserver4-with-an-angular-spa-application-for-authentication-au ?

Comment: it doesnt actually say how to send form-data instead of json for the token endpoint.

Comment: did you check the samples?

Comment: I did, the samples use MVC to send the connection, I can use my API server to handle the connection to the identity server but that is not ideal as it is going through an unprotected c# api endpoint instead of going directly to the api server.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to communicate with identity server from any javascript app, including Angular, is to use [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js). It has all you need [login, token refresh and much more](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki). Checkout this [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Clients/src/JsOidc) to see how it works.